# What is the best way to use conditional services in Bonobo?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, etl, bonobo-etl

I'd like to use Bonobo to move data from one Postgres database to another on different services. I have the connections configured and would like to use one during extraction and one during loading.

Here is my testing setup:

```
source_connection_config_env = 'DEV'
source_connection_config = get_config(source_connection_config_env)

target_connection_config_env = 'TRAINING'
target_connection_config = get_target_connection_config(target_connection_config_env)

...

def get_services(**options):
    if connection == 'source':
        return {
            'sqlalchemy.engine': create_postgresql_engine(**{
                    'host': source_connection_config.source_postres_connection['HOST'],
                    'name': source_connection_config.source_postres_connection['DATABASE'],
                    'user': source_connection_config.source_postres_connection['USER'],
                    'pass': source_connection_config.source_postres_connection['PASSWORD']
                })
        }

    if connetion == 'target':
        return {
            'sqlalchemy.engine': create_postgresql_engine(**{
                    'host': target_connection_config.target_postres_connection['HOST'],
                    'name': target_connection_config.target_postres_connection['DATABASE'],
                    'user': target_connection_config.target_postres_connection['USER'],
                    'pass': target_connection_config.target_postres_connection['PASSWORD']
                })
        }
```

I'm not sure where the best place to change connections is, or how to actually go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to use both source and target connection in the same graph (I hope I got this right).

So you cannot have this conditional, as it would return only one.

Instead, I'd return both, named differently:

```
def get_services(**options):
    return {
        'engine.source': create_postgresql_engine(**{...}),
        'engine.target': create_postgresql_engine(**{...}),
    }
```

And then use different connections in the transformations:

```
graph.add_chain(
    Select(..., engine='engine.source'),
    ...,
    InsertOrUpdate(..., engine='engine.target'),
)
```

Note that service names are just strings, there is no convention or naming pattern enforced. the 'sqlalchemy.engine' name is just the default, but you don't have to agree on it as long as you configure your transformations with the names you actually use.